# rails 4.34 mysql INSERT query doesnt work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My rails code is something simple like (code and sql output changed to make it generic)

```ruby
Router.new(
:name => params[:data][:name],
:subid => params[:data][:subid],
:info => params[:data][:info],
:parent => @parent)
```

Rails generated INSERT sql

```sql
INSERT INTO `mydb` (`name`, `subid`, `info`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "myname"], ["subid", ""], ["info", ""], ["parent_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-09-09 06:06:37"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-09 06:06:37"]]
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Mysql::Error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'parent_id' at row 1: INSERT INTO mydb (name, subid, info, parent_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Looks like  mysql doesn't like this type of syntax. I have version 5.6.32.

The values look work when I modify the command to the values directly into "VALUES". Is there a way to go back to the format where the values are inserted at "VALUES" or get the insert working without having to recreate the INSERT statement.

EDITED: I think it is not the actual the SQL. Is there a way to print the actual SQL?

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: INSERT INTO `mydb` (`name`, `subid`, `info`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "newnane"], ["subid", "SID"], ["info", "NO"], ["parent_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-09-09 07:33:26"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-09 07:33:26"]]

Mysql::Error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'parent_id' at row 1: INSERT INTO `mydb` (`name`, `subid`, `info`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: @AKS: What is the value of parent_id?

Comment: parent_id is 2 and in mysql table is "parent_id        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |              "